# How do I make mecha-style models?

Tags: texture, 3ds-max, modeling

I am rather newbish at modeling and noob at texturing. For a few weeks I have been trying to make some buildings inspired from Oblivion (the scify movie) and perhaps Elysium.
What happens is, I start modeling, and at one point or another it gets crappy. At the end I am unhappy with the result, mostly because I would need reference images, not concept art.

What would help me loads would be some models in this nature, preferably textures, so I can study them and form a mental process on how to create new things of this nature.

Thank you!

[image: image description]
[image: image description]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi there and welcome. What are those links? Your images? If so, could you please add the images to your post? And explain in detail where you feel it goes wrong?

Comment: As Boblet mentions, the links are a tiny bit confusing because they seem to have quite different styles. You ask where to find models of this nature, but you posted quite a few yourself. Do you have an example of what you have drawn / modeled and a comparison with what you are wanting to achieve? As it it, it's quite difficult to understand the question because there isn't a clear issue to work on.

Comment: None of these are mine. I saw a pattern of black skeleton with armor on and I am trying to duplicate it but the end result is not "realistic". It doesn't come out as something mechanically useful or attractive. I can't fathom what the steps to designing such a model are. I don't have graphic skills, but I can model something from imagination once I  figure out the pattern to it.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that realistic look in combination with a cartoonish layer you should build your models in a 3d modeling software and import a rendered image of your object in to Photoshop (or similar drawing software) to draw on top of the original (create a new layer on top and draw on that).

Add shadows, highlights, lightning etc. if you can in the 3d software since it will make it easier to copy in the sketching phase.